# Laravelのマイグレーションでテーブルの最新の状態を知りたい

Tags: laravel

Laravelのマイグレーションでカラムの追加や変更などを繰り返していくと、どんどんマイグレーションファイルが溜まっていくわけですが、最新のテーブルの状態を一目で確認できる方法はありますでしょうか。

mysqlに直接アクセスしたりツールを使えばテーブルの状態は確認できますが、laravelのartisanコマンドなどで簡単に確認できる方法があるといいのですが。

特に、「いろいろマイグレーションファイルを追加したけど最終的には`$table->string('name', 500);`をやったのと同じだよ」みたいな一発確認ができると一番ありがたいです。

Answer (score 0):

生 SQL での出力は Laravel 8.x からの新機能である `./artisan schema:dump --prune` を叩いておけば実現できますが，そこから更に Laravel のマイグレーションコードを逆生成する機能はいまのところ存在しませんね。

- [Laravel 8 の新機能！マイグレーションスカッシングで肥大化したマイグレーションファイルを1つにまとめる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ucan-lab/items/2f00191dcf8371347d13)